# I am writing a simple inheritance program in C++, but I got many errors

Tags: c++, inheritance

Don't know what I'm getting wrong. I'm new to inheritance. Including all errors I got:

```
21  7   D:\My C++ programs\inheritance.cpp  [Error] redefinition of 'class Sharad'
5   7   D:\My C++ programs\inheritance.cpp  [Error] previous definition of 'class Sharad'
D:\My C++ programs\inheritance.cpp  In function 'int main()':
27  2   D:\My C++ programs\inheritance.cpp  [Error] 'Sourabh' was not declared in this scope
28  2   D:\My C++ programs\inheritance.cpp  [Error] 's1' was not declared in this scope
```

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Sharad{
string a,b,c,d,e;
public:
    void getinfo()       
    {
        cout<<"Enter your Dad's full name: "<<endl;
        cin>>a;
        cout<<"Enter your full name: "<<endl;
        cin>>b;
    }
    void showinfo()   //Error no. 2-5   7   D:\My C++ programs\inheritance.cpp  [Error] previous definition of 'class Sharad'
    {
        cout<<"Your dad's name is: "<<a<<endl;
        cout<<"Your name is: "<<b<<endl;
    }   
};
  class Sharad : public Sourabh //error no. 3- D:\My C++ programs\inheritance.cpp   In function 'int main()':27 2   D:\My C++ programs\inheritance.cpp  [Error] 'Sourabh' was not declared in this scope
 {

 }; 
 int main()       //error 4- 28 2   D:\My C++ programs\inheritance.cpp  [Error] 's1' was not declared in this scope

  {
 Sourabh s1;
  s1.getinfo();
  s1.showinfo();
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always, always, *always* include any errors you get *in* your question. As text and verbatim.

Comment: `class Sharad : public Sourabh` seems to be the wrong way round - I believe you want `class Sourabh : public Sharad ` (since the first class you defined is `Sharad`)

Comment: [`using namespace std;` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2176813), never use it.

Comment: Oh I understood, Thank  a lot :)

Comment: @UnholySheep, thanks a lot sir :)

Comment: @tambre Then what should I use instead of it?

Comment: @sourabhjambale Nothing? Call all standard library functions explicitly. It avoids confusion and naming conflicts.

Comment: @tambre can you please give a example? I'm new to programming....

Comment: @sourabhjambale After removing `using namespace std;` you replace `cout << "Hello world!\n"` with `std::cout << "Hello world!\n"`, for example. This lets the readers of the code also see which functions, that you are using, are from the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Sharad : public Sourabh
```

This is the wrong way around. `Sourabh` is the new class that inherits from `Sharad`:

```
class Sourabh : public Sharad
```